# Error Domain=Parse Code=209 "The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I installed the ParseStarterProject swift version and created a new user with the following code:

```
var user = PFUser()
...
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock...
```

Then I ran the project again and I get the following errors:

2015-03-26 09:49:25.485 ParseStarterProject[14768:199520] [Error]: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.7.0)
2015-03-26 09:49:25.489 ParseStarterProject[14768:199521] [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=Parse Code=209 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 209.)" UserInfo=0x7fcda3cb6680 {error=invalid session token, code=209}

what have I done wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I thought getting the current user also performs login but it does not.
So the problem was that I was trying to save an object without performing login.

```
func login() {
    var username = username from UI or key store
    var password = password from UI or key store
    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
        println("current user is \(currentUser.username)")
        username = currentUser.username
    }
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password:password) {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            println("successful login with \(user.username)")
            self.saveSomething()
        } else {
            println("failed login with \(user.username)")
        }
    }

}

func saveSomething() {
    var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
    gameScore["score"] = 1337
    gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
    gameScore["cheatMode"] = false
    gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            println("The object has been saved")
        } else {
            println("There was a problem, check error.description")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `PFUser.currentUser()` will return nil if the user isn't logged in. You only need to perform the login in the case where it is nil (add an else block to your if statement).